# Is there any connection between Zuul, the Gatekeeper and the Zuuls that were roasted by the Sloar?

Tags: ghostbusters

As we know, Zuul, the Gatekeeper, is one of the minions of Gozer. Zuul seems to be a unique entity, the counterpart of Vinz Clortho, the Keymaster. That is, Zuul appears to be a name.  However, Vinz Clortho also says that many Shubs and Zuuls were roasted by Gozer when he took the form of the Sloar. I found a site with what [appears to be the shooting script](https://www.awesomefilm.com/script/Ghostbusters.txt), and the spelling of the two is the same.

Is this just a coincidence, or is there some connection between the two? For instance, is Zuul not Zuul, but just *a* Zuul that happens to serve Gozer?

Comment: "*Many Shubbs and **Zulls** knew what it was to be roasted in the depths of the Sloar that day, I can tell you.”* - Novelisation

Comment: @Valorum - It seems likely that the novelisation author didn't use the script and just did it by sound. The script shows "Zuuls". See also [here](https://www.theraffon.net/~spookcentral/gb1_script.htm).

Comment: Perhaps it is like ancient Samaria?  Where the civilization is named after a Goddess, but the humans living there would be Sumerians.